# Grandma's keynote

Tags: riddle, cipher, grid-deduction, anagram

> Found this note which is addressed
>   To my grandma, in her chest
>   Since she's passed now, here's my quest..
>   What tickled her interest?
>   And who invited her as guest?

[image: note]

Comment: Maybe using the anagram tag the guest is rot13(Jvyyvnz Zvyss)...

Comment: may be she was invited on 25 dec as 25 is color differently

Comment: rot13(Qrne Jvyzn Zvssyva nantenzf gb Jvyyvnz S. Sevrqzna, n snzbhf pelcgbtencure jub'f nyfb nffbpvngrq jvgu gur abiry Pelcgbabzvpba, naq urapr gur Fbyvgnver pvcure)

Comment: Call @Deusovi then.